# Load thousand files dynamically using SSIS

Tags: ssis

One folder is having thousand files and each files will be loaded to different sql server tables. How to design a SSIS package to do the task ?

For ex: 
File name: Location_12345.xlsx will be loaded into Location table
Employee_1233.txt will be loaded into Employee table
Department_123456.csv will be loaded into Department table

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes you can. Loop through the files in the folder and get whatever you need. A simple google search would give you everything you need. For example [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a package for each flow. You defined a minimum of 3 in your question.

For example, if all Locations follow the same flow then:

1. Add a foreach and choose files to loop through.
2. Define the folder
3. Define the criteria (Location*.xlsx)
4. Set the full file path to a variable
5. Add an excel connection
6. Make an expression for that variable
7. Design your data flow.
8. Delay validation on Excel Source before running.

This is a sample. You will have to do this for each file type.

Comment: @Bonzay's link provides this step by step with images.